# PowerShell version differences with variables

Tags: variables, powershell, msdeploy

I am running a script in Windows Server 2008 that has PowerShell V2 that collects the AppPool names from IIS and then deletes all of them and then deletes all of the websites and contents of those websites.  No issue.  Works beautifully.  Now, run that same script on Windows Server 2012 with PowerShell V4 with the same pools and websites and doesn't delete everything because of spaces in the names of AppPools.  Why is this only an issue in PS V4.

This is what it looks like

Also it doesn't matter in v4 whether I double quote the $site variable because it still throws the same error.  Again this is just fine in v2 and it runs WAY faster.   The exact same pools, sites, content on 2008 servers can get deleted in about 20 seconds, and on 2012 it takes several minutes and then throws errors like this and skips some stuff.

```
....
$msdeploy=Get-Command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'

foreach ($site in $list.WebAppName) {
    write-host $site
    & $msdeploy -verb:delete -dest:appPoolConfig=$site –skip:objectname=rootwebconfig32 –skip:objectname=httpCert –skip:objectname=machineconfig32 
}
```

The output is this as an example

```
2.0 DefaultAppPool

msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument '"-dest:"appPoolConfig=2.0'. All arguments must begin with "-".
At line:19 char:5
+     & $msdeploy -verb:delete -dest:appPoolConfig=$site –skip:objectname=rootwe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Unrecogn...begin with "-".:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Error count: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrongly. From MSDN documentation of [Web Deploy Command Line Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) an excerpt

> With a minor modification to its usual syntax, Web Deploy commands can
>   be run from a Windows PowerShell prompt. To do this, change the colon
>   character (:) after the verb, source, and dest arguments of the Web
>   Deploy command to an equal sign (=). In the following example, compare
>   the Web Deploy command with its PowerShell version.
>
> Web Deploy command: msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=/lm/w3svc/1
>   -dest:metakey=/lm/w3svc/2 -verbose
>
> PowerShell command: .\msdeploy.exe -verb=sync
>   -source=metakey=/lm/w3svc/1 -dest=metakey=/lm/w3svc/2 -verbose

Your command syntax should be

```
$msdeploy -verb=delete -dest=appPoolConfig=$site.trim() –skip=objectname=rootwebconfig32
–skip=objectname=httpCert –skip=objectname=machineconfig32
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.  It shows                         `msdeploy.exe : Error Code: ERROR_OBJECT_TO_BE_DELETED_DOES_NOT_EXIST
At line:19 char:5
+     & $msdeploy -verb=delete -dest=appPoolConfig=$site`                 Then it when you fix that it shows  `msdeploy.exe : Error: Unrecognized argument '"-dest=appPoolConfig= mysite"'`

Comment: Look at the error closely and you will find that, it's completely a different story altogether. This time you are getting error cause the particular object/site you are trying to delete doesn't exist and not the original posted error.

Comment: looks like your `$site` have spaces included and so you are getting error. try trimming those spaces like `$site.replace(' ','')`. Answer edited with that.

Comment: The App Pool name itself that it will compare against has spaces in it, so it will still fail if trim the spaces out of the variable.  My point here is that it works in 2008 powershell v2 and fails in 2012 powershell v4.  And its significantly slower.  What did microsoft do to this?

Comment: Also this,  `-dest=appPoolConfig=$site.replace(' ','')`  doesn't work.  $site has to be double quoted or it won't recognize it at as a variable and the `.replace()` isn't recognized.

Comment: Not sure how it did worked in Powershell V2! probably the syntax have been changed as specified in spec. But yes, you are correct `replace()` function will remove all spaces and so won't be correct. Rather use `trim()` function like `$site.trim()` that will work and will not remove in between spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would try encapsulating your param value in quotes and the statement in braces, like below:

```
& { $msdeploy -verb=delete -dest=appPoolConfig="$site" –skip=objectname=rootwebconfig32 –skip=objectname=httpCert –skip=objectname=machineconfig32 }
```

Comment: It says `At line:19 char:18
+     & {$msdeploy -verb=delete -dest=appPoolConfig="$site" –skip=objectname=rootw ...
+                  ~~~~~
Unexpected token '-verb' in expression or statement.
At line:19 char:8
+     & {$msdeploy -verb=delete -dest=appPoolConfig="$site" –skip=objectname=rootw ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.`